# Branch delay slots in MIPS architecture

Tags: computer-architecture, mips

I am dealing with a standard MIPS architecture. If I have a branch instruction, for instance, beq, I know the results of the comparison in execute. However, the branching logic is actually in memory stage. Hence, doesn't that mean that I am technically losing 3 cycles(if the branch is taken) since the correct instruction is fetched during the writeback stage of the branch instruction? See the diagram below to see what I mean:

```
beq ... 
add ...
add ...
add ...
...
label: sub

    C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 
beq F  D  X  M  W
add    F  D  X
add       F  D
add          F
sub             F
```

However, in this website: http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~ghosh/2-14-06.pdf 
it says we only lose 2 cycles. This is because they are assuming as soon as you know the results of the computation (in execute), you can also fetch the correct instruction. I believe this is false since branching logic actually happens in MEM.

Where am I mistaken?

Comment: I'm definitely not voting to close this question (as I believe it is on topic here), but you may have better luck getting this answered on SO.

Comment: If memory is fast enough to fetch in half a cycle, you can simply update PC on the downward clock edge. Or fudge it a bit.